# Bash scripts for Executable files equivalent for Windows

Tags: bash

I'm following a flask tutorial that is linux oriented and I'm having trouble following it on windows 10.

The first part involves setting variables on the terminal and running the python script

```
(virtual)$ export MOVIE_API_KEY=<Your api key>
(virtual)$ export SECRET_KEY=<Your secret key>
(virtual)$ python3.6  manage.py server
```

It then gives a simpler alternative which entails creating a bash script file `start.sh`:

```
export MOVIE_API_KEY=<Your api key>
export SECRET_KEY=<Your secret key>

python3.6 manage.py server
```

then making it executable, (the shell script, I believe):

```
(virtual)$ chmod a+x start.sh
```

I've been able to replicate this on windows to a point. I set the variables on command prompt:

```
SET MOVIE_API_KEY=<Your api key>
SET SECRET_KEY=<Your secret key>
```

but I'm stuck on how to make it similarly executable as its possible on linux by running `(virtual)$ chmod a+x start.sh`

How can this be done on windows?

Comment: If those two environment variables are all that is in `start.sh`, then put them, and the cal to python into a `.bat` file, say `start.bat` and use that.  The `chmod` is not required - Windows security is totally different to Linux.

Comment: This has really nothing to do with Python, the question is just about scripting on MS Windows. I removed the Python tag for that reason.